# Como acessar o valor alterado de uma variável de outra classe?

Tags: flutter, dart

Eu tenho duas classes, classe da tela inicial do meu app (HomeScreen) e a classe do meu botão (Button).

Eu tenho essa função na classe do meu botão:

```
bool variável = false;

void alterarValor() {
  setState((){
    variável = !variável;
  })
}
```

Depois de alterar o valor dessa variável na minha classe do botão, como eu passo o valor dela em tempo real para minha classe da tela inicial?

Porque mesmo executando a função, o valor não altera na classe da tela inicial, ele fica no valor inicial da variável.

O que eu faço? kkkkkkkkkk

Estou realmente estagnado nisso :/

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Pesquise sobre gerenciamento de estado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como apontado nos comentários, este tópico se chama [gerenciamento de estado](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt) (em inglês).

Sobre isso, existem muitas soluções aplicáveis e cada uma tem seus prós e contras. Qual a melhor para sua aplicação depende muito de como ela está estruturada e como seu estado é manipulado. Para uma aplicação grande, esse é uma decisão *muito* importante. Sem dúvidas é algo que rende muitas horas de discussão e debate.

Porém, como exemplo, deixo uma das maneiras mais simples de fazer o que você quer.

Sua classe do botão deve receber como parâmetro uma `Function` que servirá de *callback* para quando for clicada:

```
class MeuBotao extends StatelessWidget {
MeuBotao({this.callback});
final Function callback;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
            onPressed: callback,
            child: Text('Texto do botão'),
          );
  }
}
```

Sua classe principal `HomeScreen` que deverá gerenciar o estado da variável agora. Crie uma função que irá ser chamada quando o botão for pressionado:

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
    bool variavel = false;
    
    void alterarValor() {
            setState((){
                variável = !variável;
            })
    }
[...]
}
```

E quando construir o botão, ele recebe como parâmetro este callback:

```
child: MeuBotao(callback: alterarValor),
```

Portanto, algumas ressalvas:

- Usando **apenas** este método dificilmente seu programa será escalável para uma aplicação maior. Se houver uma árvore de widgets mais complexa, serão necessários vários callbacks que chamam uns aos outros. É impraticável e muito fácil de se confundir e gerar erros.
- No exemplo coloquei seu botão como `StatelessWidget`. Se ele precisar do valor da `variável` para se desenhar, pode receber como parâmetro que o próprio `setState()` superior irá reconstruí-lo. Ele pode possuir estado também, se necessário. Pode haver mais ações dentro do seu `onPressed` e no final chamar o callback. A customização fica por conta do uso.
- A Google chama essa solução de ["Levantar o estado"](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple#lifting-state-up) (do inglês: *Lifting state up*). Isso ocorre porque a variável de estado estava presente em um widget mais abaixo na árvore de widgets e foi movida para um widget mais superior. Este por sua vez consegue passar ela para todos os Widgets que a precisam.

Comment: Muito Obrigado! Ajudou mesmo