# Como passar variáveis de um Widget reutilizável para uma tela no flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

Olá, eu estou buscando reaproveitar alguns widgets do meu app, irei dar um exemplo resumido.
Tenho uma AppBar, que no caso é meu Menu Geral, presente em todas as telas.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class MenuGeral extends StatelessWidget  implements PreferredSize {
  bool exibirConteudo = false;
  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(100);
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar( // CABEÇALHO
      title: "Text",
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu,color: Colors.white),
            onPressed: (){
              exibirConteudo= !exibirConteudo;
              print("$exibirConteudo");
            }
        )
      ],
       ...
    );
  }
```

Como visto, ela tem uma variável chamada exibirConteudo

Eu preciso passar essa variável exibirConteudo para uma outra tela chamada

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:meuPackage/widgets/menu_geral.dart';
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
 bool _exibirConteudo = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: MenuGeral(),
      body: Visibility(
          visible: exibirConteudo,
          return widgetQueQueroExibir(),
      )
      ...
    );
}
```

Eu já consegui colocar o widget nas telas necessárias, mas não consigo pega o valor da variável ativarSubmenu de Menu Geral.
Preciso pegar o valor dessa variável, porque no corpo do meu Home, tem um widget Visibility que recebe esse valor, para obviamente, exibir ou não outro Widget 
Qual é uma boa maneira de fazer isso, sem dar um Navigator.replacement passando a variavel a partir do MenuGeral?

**Resumidamente, quero conseguir usar uma variável booleana de um Widget reutilizável(Stateless) em todas as outras telas do meu app(StateFull), para executar uma ação, sem usar Navigator.push, se possível.**

Answer (score 2):

Segue um exemplo de sugestão:

- Na sua classe de AppBar, receba como parâmetro uma função para servir de callback:

```
class MenuGeral extends StatelessWidget  implements PreferredSize {
  MenuGeral({this.callback});
  final Function callback;
  bool exibirConteudo = false;
  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(100);
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar( // CABEÇALHO
      title: "Text",
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu,color: Colors.white),
            onPressed: (){
              exibirConteudo= !exibirConteudo;
              print("$exibirConteudo");
              callback(exibirConteudo); // Chame-a aqui.
            }
        )
      ],
       ...
    );
  }
```

obs: Não se esqueça de chamá-la dentro do `onTap:`

- Na classe de estado da sua tela, crie essa função que vai ser passada por parâmetro:

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
    void callbackDaAppBar(bool variavel){
        setState((){_exibirConteudo = variavel;});
    }
    bool _exibirConteudo = false;
    [...]
}
```

- Quando criar a appBar, passe como parâmetro a função criada:

```
[...]
appBar: MenuGeral(callback:callbackDaAppBar),
[...]
```

Isso deve ser o suficiente para fazer funcionar o que você deseja. Assim cada tela pode fazer o que quiser com a informação da `appBar`. Se todas as telas fazem a mesma coisa, você pode criar outro Widget próprio porém que já contém o que foi feito acima, e automaticamente chama o setState quando a visibilidade muda, mas aí já é uma solução bem mais sofisticada.

Existem muitas outras formas para resolver tal situação. Elas envolvem um conhecimento e planejamento maior de seu gerenciamento de estado. Para isso, sugiro fortemente ler [essa fonte](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options) e [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/482936/152025) como consultas adicionais.

Comment: Agradeço sua atenção, irei buscar aprender sobre gerenciamento de estado.
Sua resposta embora dedicada não resolve meu problema, afinal o que eu preciso é uma espécie de interruptor, Ligado e Desligado, alternando sempre que o botão for clicado.

Implementei sua função, mas ela vai apenas negar a constante de inicialização do menu geral.
Ou seja, ele exibe o widget, mas se eu clicar novamente ele não fecha.

De qualquer maneira obrigado.

Comment: pode me tirar só uma dúvida? Ainda é sobre esse problema, pesquisei sobre o padrão Bloc, implementei, mas meu StreamBuilder só recebe a 1º atualização.

Passo o dado no sink, mas a saída não muda no StreamBuilder, tem alguma orientação da razão disso?